# Unpacking Vector/Set in for loop

Tags: c++, c++17

Like in Python, we can unpack list of lists in a for loop as follows:

```py
coordinates = [[2,2], [5,99]]
for x, y in coordinates:
    print(x+y)
```

Is there any way to do the same with vector/set of vectors/sets in C++?
Somewhat Like

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> coordinates {{2,3}, {5,99}};
for(auto x, y : coordinates)
    cout << x+y;
```

It's going to be nicer, if someone can provide solution in multiple c++ versions.

Comment: You should choose a specific standard because the answer will differ a lot between c++11/c++14 and c++17.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't it be awesome to have solution to such question in different c++ versions at one place itself? It'll even enhance stack-overflow's answers' quality. Anyone, who wants to know this but use different versions will get pacified here.

Comment: If you want answer for multiple C++ versions, clarify it in your question so that answers start including solutions for all C++ versions. Currently, user will look for this and see a question for c++11 and only find c++17 answers, so that's not really nice for other users. When you use multiple versions tags, people select the one they feel the most appropriate, they do not try to address all versions, as you can see since all anssers are C++17 only, there are no C++11/C++14 answers (likely because there are no solutions for these versions).

Comment: Sure, I will add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not with `vector<vector<int>>` because the size of (the inner) vector is not known at compile time. You need `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> coordinates {{2,3}, {5,99}};
for(auto [x,y] : coordinates)
    cout << x+y;
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that in your Q you have asked for unpacking a list of lists (as in Python). You can improve @bolov's answer by using an `std::array` (instead of a `std::pair`) inside your vector to have any number of elements in your inner container:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> coordinates{ {2,3,4}, {5,99,23} };
for (auto[x, y, z] : coordinates)
   std::cout << x + y + z;
    
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
```

Comment: What is your improvement by using an array instead of a pair? Especially, why we have now 3 parms per set while OP asks explicitly for 2...

Comment: @Gupta This doesn't seem like an improvement over bolov's answer. How is this an improvement over bolov's answer, please specify?

Comment: @Klaus the original question refers to a list of lists in python, i.e. no limitation on the number of elements in the inner list. Although bolov's answer is sound, but in his/her answer the inner container (i.e. pair) can have only two elements inside. So, I proposed this solution to relax a little bit this limitation.

Comment: @AanchalSharma As the comment, mentioned for Klaus.

Comment: If you really want to have a python like list, the only valid type is an std::array of std::tuple<bool, int, string> :-) But I don't believe that all this is helpful :-)

Comment: @Klaus Agreed ! not possible to emulate all features of the flexible Python lists in C++. And it is normal for an early-bound language like C++ :-)